# Left Handed controller

Tags: controllers, rock-band, guitar-hero

Whilst I am right-handed in pretty much everything, I am not when it comes to playing guitar (real or otherwise).

Are there left handed controllers available from Rock Band/Guitar Hero...? If I'm using a normal controller, then the whammy bar is above strum bar, and quite annoying...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, no, there are no left-handed guitar controllers available.  You'll have to either play right-handed, or deal with the whammy bar being on the wrong side of the strum bar.

If the whammy bar falls onto your hand as you're playing, you can try using a rubber band or two to hold it up.

Comment: Or crack open the controller case and move the whammy bar to a better location for you. ;)  I've also noticed that some controllers (the bass for instance), have a knob whammy, which may not get in your way as much, and it would probably actually be more useful for a lefty if at the top of the controller (it is a pain to reach all the way to the bottom of the guitar and twist it; my wrist inevitably hits the strum bar.

Answer (score -2):

Actually, most Guitar Hero games have a "Lefty Flip" option, and most Guitar Hero controllers have a way to put the strap in an orientation for left-handed play. Go to Settings (or Extras in later games) to find this.

Comment: This doesn't resolve the whammy bar issue that he referred to.